# why in spite of increasing the physical size of my text file its .gz compressed size shows significant decrease in size

Tags: linux, compression, sed

I have a large test file which its `.gz` format is about 13 GB. I have replaced a substring in the original file and compressed the file to `.gz` format.

To do so, I used the following Linux command:

```
zcat $inFile | sed -e "s/0\/0:.:.:./0\/0:.:1,0,0:./g"  | gzip > $outFile
```

`0/0:.:.:.` —> `0/0:.:1,0,0:`.

As you can see I have replaced one character with 5 characters, still the output file is which is gripped is about 12 GB in physical size.

Can someone help me to understand what is happening here?

Comment: compression is not usually deterministic across all similar inputs, so there is always a degree of opportunism based on the actual input (eg all random strings of 128 chars will not all compress to the same size; all 40x80 256-color bitmaps will not compress to the same size, etc).

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` command has a syntax that includes the use of wildcard special characters. Among these special characters, the `.` stands for *any* character.

So the command:

```
sed -e "s/0\/0:.:.:./0\/0:.:1,0,0:./g"
```

will replace 3 *random* characters that fit between sequences of `:` with the actual character `.` or other *fixed* value, thus lowering entropy.

For example it will replace these 6 lines:

```
0/0:a:b:c
0/0:d:e:f
0/0:g:h:i
0/0:j:k:l
0/0:m:n:o
0/0:p:q:r
```

with:

```
0/0:.:1,0,0:.
0/0:.:1,0,0:.
0/0:.:1,0,0:.
0/0:.:1,0,0:.
0/0:.:1,0,0:.
0/0:.:1,0,0:.
```

which is 6 times the repetition of the exact same line: much better able to be compressed to a smaller size.

While above is most probably the main reason compression improves, in addition, as suggested by Patrick Abraham (and by Kamil Maciorowski) an other mechanism is also possible: if parts already contained `0/0:.:1,0,0:.` before using `sed`, then creating more identical parts also lowers entropy and thus improves compression, even if `.` had not been a special character.

Comment: Even if ``.`` wouldn't be seen as a wildcard, the entropy could still be lowered. It wouldn't be a huge jump, still in a theory it could have an effect.

Comment: @PatrickAbraham if you have a bijection from the first file to the second file, entropy stays the same (you could always transform the file back into its former state if it helps compression). Here, the transformation is not reversible: it maps multiple possibilities (an arbitrary character) into a single possibility, the `.` character: there's less entropy in the result. That because of this that the resulting compression can be smaller.  Though I admit that without the . as a wildcard, this might still not be a bijection (can't tell) so it might still be possible to have lowered the entropy.

Comment: Yes, but I never spoke about bijections nor any reversible maps. I spoke purely about the theoretical possibility that ``0/0:.:1,0,0:.`` and ``0/0:.:.:.`` are glyphs in the file hence this map would remove ``0/0:.:.:.`` as a glyph thus lowering the entropy of the file, even if ``.`` isn't handled as a wildcard.
This kind of map is rarely injective on such a big file, hence it would most likely reduce the entropy, at least if the replacement of the given string is something sensible given the context.

Isn't reducing entropy the nature of none injectivity?

Comment: @PatrickAbraham Ah yes, I think this was also suggested in the (now deleted) other answer: if parts are made the same this also lowers entropy, now I get it.